# CSS - Image loading

Tags: css, image

I'm having a little problem, I have a header image that is quite large and takes time to load on bad internet connections. I've seen some websites load their bigger image files from "low quality" -> "normal quality (original)", rather than "no-image" -> "loaded image".. what I seem to be having with my header.

```
background-image:url("images/header");
```

Is there a way to make the image load from low quality to high quality rather than no image to image in CSS?

I'm really sorry if I expressed my problem badly. English is not my native language :)

Comment: Can you link to the header image? Just curious to see if there are other optimizations to make to its size as well.

Comment: http://www.upload.ee/image/2532054/header.png

Comment: [Progressive Image Rendering](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/12/progressive-image-rendering.html)

Comment: +1 for @Shvetusya. This is the best option if you want to use **only** CSS.

Comment: I saved the png file with "Interlaced" check in photoshop, but it doensn't load it like that... Is there something i didn't understand?

demo: http://kdfx.eu/designs/piupiuhq/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `lowsrc` Attribute :

```
<img alt="Image Name" src="highquality.jpg" lowsrc="lowquality.jpg">
```

Comment: With CSS i need this to be done, i have background-image.. but if i have no other options i'll try this.

Comment: I don't think there's such option in CSS, instead wrap your header div with another and make its background-image source to low quality but here, two images will be loaded unnecessarily..